# Querydsl-sql specify table name with schema

Tags: maven, querydsl

I would like to achieve following:

I want to use `querydsl-jpa` and `querydsl-sql` alongside.
SQL version for usages where I can not use jpa and JPA for all other things.
To avoid decisions where to connect app while build, I would like to commit the SQL classes into repository (and therefore there will be no need to connect build to database).

The usages where I can not use jpa will be minimum, therefore I would like to implicitly specify the tables I would like to generate the `QS` classes (QS is my choosen prefix for Querydsl-sql classes and Q is the prefix for Querydsl-jpa classes).

I´ve found in documentation there is possibility to use `tableNamePattern`. And I am configuring the `querydsl-maven-plugin` like this (the plugin is accessible only for specific maven profile so when I do not specify this profile, app should be able to build without any connections to database, it should just use the commited generated classes).

```
                <configuration>
                    <jdbcDriver>org.postgresql.Driver</jdbcDriver>
                    <jdbcUrl>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db</jdbcUrl>
                    <jdbcUser>db</jdbcUser>
                    <jdbcPassword>pw</jdbcPassword>
                    <packageName>querydsl</packageName>
                    <targetFolder>querydsl</targetFolder>
                    <namePrefix>QS</namePrefix>
                    <nameSuffix>Bo</nameSuffix>
                    <tableNamePattern>table_name,another_table</tableNamePattern>
                    <sourceFolder/>
                </configuration>
```

But. I have 2 schemas in my database. Lets name it `public` and `internal`.

My question is: **How can I specify the schema of table in `tableNamePattern` configuration?**
In case I have just public version of `table_name`, it generates one QsTableNameBo class.
But what If there are 2 tables with same name in both schemas and I want to ecplicitly say, generated QS class only from public.

I´ve tried something like `public.table_name` but plugin did not generated any output.

Comment: Have you try to configure (set) also schemaPattern? http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.2/reference/html/ch02s03.html